# Función para generar siglas de una oración en mysql

Tags: mysql

Busco hacer una función para generar iniciales de una oración sin importar que tan larga sea la oración y poder decir con qué separar las iniciales. Ej.: `(hola mundo mysql,-)` =  `h-m-m`

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `separacionDinamica`(separador VARCHAR(100),texto VARCHAR (100)) 
RETURNS varchar(100)
        DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE aux INT;
    DECLARE num INT;
    DECLARE siglas VARCHAR (100);
    
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tabla;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tabla(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,dato VARCHAR (100));
    
    INSERT INTO tabla                               ---------esto le hace un split a una oracion y lo introduce cada palabra de la oracion en una fila  
    SELECT string_split(texto,' ')AS iniciales;     -------- el string_split es un strored porcedure
    SET aux =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla);          ------- hace conteo de las filas para meterlo en el while
    
    SET num=1;
    WHILE (@num<=@aux)DO                            
    SET siglas= concat(' ',siglas,(SELECT substring(dato,1,1), separador FROM tabla WHERE id=num));
    SET num =num+1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN UPPER (siglas);
    
END
```

pero a la hora de llamar a la función me sale

> Error Code: 1305

El código del split es este:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `string_split`(
  IN cadena text,
  IN separador varchar(1)
)
BEGIN
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS split;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE split(vals text); 
  WHILE LOCATE(separador,cadena) > 1 DO
    INSERT INTO split SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(cadena,separador,1);
    SET cadena = REPLACE(cadena, (SELECT LEFT(cadena, LOCATE(separador, cadena))),'');
  END WHILE;
  INSERT INTO split(vals) VALUES(cadena);
  SELECT TRIM(vals) FROM split;
END
```

Comment: Pero eso no es una funcion, es un procedure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes implementar la función de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE FUNCTION separacionDinamica(separador VARCHAR(100), texto VARCHAR (100)) 
RETURNS varchar(100) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
  DECLARE palabras varchar(100);
  DECLARE palabra VARCHAR (100);
  DECLARE posicion INT;
  DECLARE siglas VARCHAR (100);

  SET @palabras := texto;
  SET @siglas := "";

  WHILE LENGTH(@palabras) > 0 DO
      SELECT POSITION(separador IN @palabras) INTO @posicion;

      IF @posicion > 0 THEN
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@palabras, 1, @posicion - 1) INTO @palabra;

        IF LENGTH(@palabra) > 0 THEN         
          SELECT CONCAT(@siglas, CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(@palabra, 1)), '-')) INTO @siglas;
        END IF;

        SELECT SUBSTRING(@palabras, @posicion + 1) INTO @palabras;

      ELSE
        SELECT CONCAT(@siglas, CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(@palabras, 1)), '-')) INTO @siglas;
        SET @palabras := "";
      END IF;

  END WHILE;

  SELECT SUBSTRING(@siglas, 1, LENGTH(@siglas) - 1) INTO @siglas;

  RETURN @siglas;

END
```

Para **MySql >= 8.0** puedes implementar la función utilizando una query recursiva (similar a la respuesta de @Sal):

```
CREATE FUNCTION separacionDinamica(separador VARCHAR(100), texto VARCHAR (100)) 
RETURNS varchar(100) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
  DECLARE res varchar(100);

  WITH RECURSIVE aux AS (
    SELECT texto AS oracion, 
            LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(texto, separador, 1), 1) AS letra

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUBSTRING(oracion, POSITION(separador IN oracion) + 1),
           LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(oracion, POSITION(separador IN oracion) + 1), separador, 1), 1)
    FROM aux
    WHERE POSITION(separador IN oracion) > 0)

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(UPPER(letra) separator '-') INTO @res FROM aux WHERE letra != '';

  RETURN @res;

END
```

El concepto utilizado en ambas funciones es similar, lo que varia es la forma de implementarlo.

Un ejemplo de llamada a la función:

```
SELECT separacionDinamica("#", "Esto#es#una#prueba.");
```

Resultado: **E-E-U-P**

En ambas funciones, en caso de que el texto tenga dos separadores consecutivos, omitirá el segundo (en lugar de retornar en el resultado dos guiones consecutivos).

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL >= 8 lo puedes conseguir con una *Expresión de Tabla Común Recursiva* recortando la cadena con `substring()` hasta que no se encuentre el separador, y generando en cada recursión un registro por cada palabra. Una vez creada la CTE, simplemente se agrupa el primer caracter de cada palabra usando el separador `-`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE palabras( palabra, cadena ) as(
  SELECT cast( null as CHAR(255) )
       , 'hola mundo mysql'
  UNION
  SELECT substring_index(cadena,' ',1)
       , if( locate(' ',cadena)
           , substring( cadena
                      , locate(' ',cadena)+1
                      )  
           , null
           )
    FROM palabras
    WHERE cadena is not null
)
SELECT group_concat( left(palabra,1) separator '-' ) iniciales
  FROM palabras
  WHERE palabra is not null
```

Resultado:

```
+-----------+
| iniciales |
+-----------+
| h-m-m     |
+-----------+
```